# Share files between Public IP & Private IP

Tags: file-sharing

I'm trying to share some files between my laptop and my desktop, however My desktop is assigned with a public IP as opposed to a private IP like 192.168.1.102.  The reason being that it's just more convenient for me to leave it as a public Ip because of utorrent.

Is there anyway for me to share files between my desktop and laptop?

Comment: It's not that hard to set a static private IP & open port(s) for µtorrent: http://www.portforward.com/networking/staticip.htm & http://www.portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/Utor/Utorindex.htm ... And it's more secure to have a router between you and internet...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I presume that your laptop is actually using a private IP.
Networking between these two machines in your 'home' network
(that is, without communicating over the Internet)
will need a private IP configured on your desktop (this is easily done with an alias)

How are the laptop, desktop and the Internet path connected?
Do you have two interfaces on the desktop (say one wireless and one wired)
such that one is used to connect to the Internet and the other to connect with your laptop?
If you can get this done, it would be as simple as setting up a private IP address
in the same subnet as your laptop on this second interface of your desktop.

Comment: My laptop has the public IP, desktop has a private IP.  I use the laptop to bitorrent, and it would not be feasible for me to use the wireless for internet.

And yes I do know how to port forward, it's just that the router I'm using is quite crappy, and the only way I have been able to get it to work with bitorrent was to assign the laptop with the public IP.

I suppose I could use FTP, but I was hoping for something a little more convenient like homegroup.

Comment: The machine that has the private IP (you need to edit your comment or question to be consistent) - you need to tell us how it is getting internet access, if it is.  If the machine that has a private IP is not connected via a wire or wireless to any router, bridge, or switch, you're going to need to use sneakernet to transfer files unless you want to get into esoteric things like using serial/paralell cables.

Answer (score 0):

FTP would work.

You can find both client and server at: http://filezilla-project.org/ (free)